# flutter error) Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator, build-error

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,ß
}
```

I can't find a solution for this error.
ask for help

Answer (score 0):

I would try to open the terminal and from the project directory call these commands
`cd ios`
`pod deintegrate`
`pod install`
In this way you would clean up the podfile and hopefully it can resolve the problem